# How can I fix ViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Im new to iOS programming. I tried to make known HelloWorld application but the application does not work.

part of the

> ```
> return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
> ```
>
> Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT error.

```
2013-10-28 19:52:07.872 MerhabaDunya[2341:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/bb/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/32CBEFAF-FFFB-4550-990A-6A33B02CF7D6/MerhabaDunya.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x017395e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bc8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x017393bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
3   UIKit                               0x004cb39c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 951
4   UIKit                               0x0033d605 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
5   UIKit                               0x0033ddad -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
6   UIKit                               0x0033e0ae -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
7   UIKit                               0x0033e5b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
8   UIKit                               0x002669fd -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
9   UIKit                               0x00266d97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
10  UIKit                               0x0026702d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
11  UIKit                               0x0027189a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
12  MerhabaDunya                        0x00002cdb -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 683
13  UIKit                               0x00224355 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
14  UIKit                               0x00224b95 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1536
15  UIKit                               0x002293a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
16  UIKit                               0x0023d87c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
17  UIKit                               0x0023dde9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
18  UIKit                               0x0022b025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
19  GraphicsServices                    0x036e02f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
20  GraphicsServices                    0x036dfe01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
21  CoreFoundation                      0x016b4d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
22  CoreFoundation                      0x016b4a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
23  CoreFoundation                      0x016df77c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
24  CoreFoundation                      0x016deac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
25  CoreFoundation                      0x016de8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
26  UIKit                               0x00228add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
27  UIKit                               0x0022ad3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
28  MerhabaDunya                        0x00002f2d main + 141
29  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7770d start + 1
30  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)


libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

appdelegate.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewController;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@end
```

appdeledage.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window=_window;
@synthesize viewController=_viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController=[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController=self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

ViewController.m
    #import "ViewController.h"

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize etiket;
@synthesize tus;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)basildi:(id)sender {
    [etiket setText:@"Hello"];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stack trace, it appears that you are trying to instantiate a `UIViewController` with the method `-initWithNibName:bundle:` but with a non-existent or nil nib name.

Make sure that the nib name parameter that you are passing in does exist i.e. a file exists with the name `ExampleViewController.xib`, or the parameter is not nil.

Edit---

Now that you've posted your code, I can clarify further. The file `ViewController.xib` does not exist, and needs to be created. Alternatively, you may have a typo. Compare the string to the `xib`, if any, in your main bundle.

Edit---

Now that you mentioned storyboards, you should just return YES in your `-...didFinishLaunching...` method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboards then you should not be calling initWithNibName. It sounds like you're trying to mix code from an XIB-based app into a storyboard based app. That won't work.

Rip all that code out of your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. Simply return YES.